Campo SQL en Imapala
Necesito concatenar un campo fecha con un id que sea autoincremental.
Hice esto:
CONCAT(CAST(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pfcertibf.id_operacion ORDER BY pfcertibf.id_operacion) AS STRING), '-', pfcertibf.fecha_proceso) AS clave_registro

Pero es demasiado pesada y hace que la query completa no funcione

el id_operacion es único?
